# RSA private key differs in Eclipse and CommandLine

Tags: java, security

I have some trouble with signing data with private key and verifying it later with the public key.

I have generated private/public key pair and save the keys in a file per key. First I create Hash of the data I want to sign:

```
byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(password);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(digest, 16), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

return cipher.doFinal(serializeLicense(data));
```

After that I sign the data with my private key:

```
PrivateKey key = loadPrivateKey();
Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
dsa.initSign(key);

dsa.update(data);
return dsa.sign();
```

My problem is that this code seems to give different output. When I run it in eclipse I can verify the resulting signed data with the public key. But when I run the code via command line then the signed data cannot be verified.

Further analysis shows that the method loadPrivateKey() is the problem:

```
 PrivateKey privateKey = null;

 try
 {
     InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keys/rsa_key");
     byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[in.available()];
     in.read(encodedPrivateKey);
     in.close();

     LOG.info(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encodedPrivateKey), "UTF-8"));

     privateKey = toPrivateKey(encodedPrivateKey);
 }
 catch (IOException ex) 
 {
     LOG.error("private key not found", ex);
 }

 return privateKey;
```

The logging of the encodedPrivateKey gives a minimal different output between running in eclipse and running on command line. The keys are same except the last 7 chars. Where does this difference come from?

Comment: Different Java version maybe? Check which JRE you are using in Eclipse and then run `java -version` on the command line.

Comment: Nope, both are 1.8.0_60 64-Bit.

Comment: First of all don't ever use `available()`. You're assuming that it returns the size of the file, which it's not guaranteed to do. You can check whether eclipse and the command line end up with different length `encodedPrivateKey` arrays. That's the most obvious error in your code.